# What is the source of energy of the universe?

Tags: energy, cosmology, energy-conservation, universe, big-bang

For example, our human body obtains the energy for work by food, water etc for the nutrition, the plants require water, fertilizer for nutrition to produce food, machines require fuel to work, may it be in any form, there is a source of energy, obtaining which the work is done. Keeping in mind the law of conservation of energy, there are sources of energy too. What is the source of energy for this universe to work? For the planets to rotate and revolve? For the galaxies, asteroids, meteors, stars and their formations to happen?

Answer (score 4):

It is quite possible that the total [energy content of the universe is zero](https://www.livescience.com/33129-total-energy-universe-zero.html). The energy in the radiation and matter of the universe is positive, while the energy of the gravitational fields caused by matter and energy is negative.

As a result, if the universe is flat, the two may balance out. As current measurements indicate that the universe is indeed flat, this leaves us without any requirement for extra energy.

The flatness of the universe is indicated by a number of observations. The total [mass/radiation content](https://wmap.gsfc.nasa.gov/media/080998/) of the universe seems to have the required value, if we include dark matter and dark energy. Inflation as we understand it produces a flat universe. And measurements of the Cosmic Microwave Background also imply it is flat.

As a result, the universe could indeed [start from nothing at all](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1451624468), and there is no requirement for any extra energy to get things moving.